# C++ Equivalent of VLOOKUP function

Tags: c++, csv, vlookup

I'm trying to create an equivalent of the excel VLOOKUP function for a two dimensional csv file I have.  If given a number 5 I would like to be able to look at a column of a dynamic table I have and find the row with the highest number less than five in that column.

For example.  If I used 5 from my example before:

```
2  6
3  7
4  11
6  2
9  4
```

Would return to me 11, the data paired with the highest entry below 5.

I have no idea how to go about doing this.  If it helps, the entries in column one (the column I will be searching) will go from smallest to largest.

I am a beginner to C++ so I apologize if I'm missing some obvious method.

Comment: What's your data structure for this? If you're looking at two integers like that, then `std::map<int, int>` would be appropriate. Is that what you have? Or do you have a 2-D array of `int`?

Comment: It's two integers.  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: OK, it's two integers, but what are you storing them in? Is it a `std::map` or not? Have you written that code yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` can do this pretty easily:

You'd start by creating a map of the correct type, then populating it with your data:

```
std::map<int, int, std::greater<int> > data;

data[2] = 6;
data[3] = 7;
data[4] = 11;
data[6] = 2;
data[9] = 4;
```

Then you'd search for data with `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`:

```
std::cout << data.lower_bound(5)->second; // prints 11
```

A couple of notes: First, note the use of `std::greater<T>` as the comparison operator. This is necessary because `lower_bound` will normally return an iterator to the *next* item (instead of the previous) if the key you're looking for isn't present in the map. Using `std::greater<T>` sorts the map in reverse, so the "next" item is the smaller one instead of the larger.

Second, note that this automatically sorts the data based on the keys, so it depends only on the data you insert, not the order of insertion.

Comment: And if the data of my map is dynamic and more entries can be added?

Comment: @user2570010: Maps are designed to handle dynamic addition/deletion, so if you want to add more, that's not a problem.